# letters in emnist training dataset are rotated and little vague

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset

I am using emnist-letters-train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz and emnist-letters-train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz from http://biometrics.nist.gov/cs_links/EMNIST/gzip.zip
I wrote this little script to see images

```py
import os
import struct
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')
path = './'
fname_img = os.path.join(path, 'emnist-letters-train-images-idx3-ubyte')
fname_lbl = os.path.join(path, 'emnist-letters-train-labels-idx1-ubyte')
with open(fname_lbl, 'rb') as flbl:
        magic, num = struct.unpack(">II", flbl.read(8))
        lbl = np.fromfile(flbl, dtype=np.int8)
with open(fname_img, 'rb') as fimg:
    magic, num, rows, cols = struct.unpack(">IIII", fimg.read(16))
    img = np.fromfile(fimg, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(len(lbl), rows, cols)
print 'image',img.shape
print 'label',lbl.shape
labels, indices = np.unique(lbl,return_index=True)
print 'unique labels',labels
print 'unique indices',indices
    for i in indices:
        image = img[i]
        for y in image:
            row = ""
            for x in y:
                row += '{0: <4}'.format(x)
            print row
        print 'label',lbl[i],'\n'
        newfilename = str(lbl[i]) + '.jpg'
        scipy.misc.imsave(newfilename, image)
```

Here is the output image [image: montage of letters a to z] 

My question is that - i and l are undifferentiable , r is unrecognizable , ,many letters are inverted . Why is that ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should rotate data anti-clockwise by 90 degrees

Comment: see https://imgur.com/a/IEQ0J . some images became OK but not all .

Answer (score 2):

Flip the image horizontally and then rotate it 90 degrees anti-clockwise.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is likely the way you're reading the dataset arrays. If you transpose the array being read (e.g., for a numpy array, `your_array.T`), your EMNIST characters should be in the correct orientation.

Answer (score 2):

snippet to transform eminst in pytorch (just to see transforms necessary)

```
dataset = torchvision.datasets.EMNIST(
                path_data,
                download=True,
                split='balanced',
                train=not is_test_data,
                transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                    lambda img: torchvision.transforms.functional.rotate(img, -90),
                    lambda img: torchvision.transforms.functional.hflip(img),
                    torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
                ])
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ankit Tiwari has told .
After flipping horizontally and rotating , it looks ok .
Thanks.
See [image: looks ok a to z]

Answer (score 0):

This works in Ubuntu 16.04 / Anaconda 3.6, despite Python 2 just comment out Print ... quick way to validate EMNIST balanced and MNIST loading